# Rails automatically escpaping HTML - how to stop it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on upgrading an old Rails app (1.1.6) to Rails 3.  Obviously, a lot has changed.  One thing appears to be that Rails automatically escapes content dropped into the view.  However, I have a situation where I have a helper generating IMG tags for me, and Rails is automatically escaping the resulting content.

```
<%= random_image('public/images/headers') %>
```

This results in escaped content, much like one would expect had I done this (in 1.1.6)

```
<%= h random_image('public/images/headers') %>
```

Is there a way to tell it to *not* escape?

Comment: You should really get into the habit of reading RELEASENOTES. What "h" used to do is now the default behavior as of Rails 3, and you have to do something in order to NOT get automatic escaping. Just [command].html_safe any string-producing commands, or put then inside raw(...), as people below say. Oh, and READ THE RELEASENOTES. Always. Really. :)

Comment: @Mörre I wasn't sure which release notes to read, to be honest. Had no idea if this was a Rails 2.x feature, or 3.x feature - and there are SO many releases, and SO many details for each release.

Comment: @Mörre A valid point, I concede.  I have to admit, it's a bit daunting, and was hoping for a quick fix to a simple problem.  I'm not looking forward to parsing through those notes, considering that I know there were 1.1.6 -> 2.x changes that are no longer relevant in 3.x.  I will probably 'start from scratch' as far as learning, and pick up a good Rails 3 book/tutorial at the first opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.html_safe
```

It may need to be inside the helper

Comment: It's convention to use the raw method in your views and .html_safe in your helpers but either way works.

Comment: thanks, I'd never even heard of raw, picked up the .html_safe on the railscasts for migrating from 2 to 3

Answer (score 5):

```
<%= raw random_image('public/images/headers') %>
```

Comment: Best solution for spitting JSON form controller to view imo.

Answer (score 2):

There are there ways in which this can be achieved in rails 3 application

1. html_safe
2. raw
3. h

raw and h can only be used in controller and views these methods are defined in helpers.

html_safe can be used anywhere in a rails application i.e., can be used in models, helpers, controller etc.

For more information please read http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Comment: Ahem, "h" is the OPPOSITE of "raw", same as it always was. Only 1. and 2. are solutions to the question.